# An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker.' triggerred while updating the record from the View on POST

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am trying to update the entry on the post method from the controller. It throws me the error "System.InvalidOperationException: 'An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker.'" on 'context.Entry(project).State = EntityState.Modified;' this statement which is updating the record in the else part. Can anyone help me here? Thanks in advance

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EditProject(ProjectViewModel projectViewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                Projects project;
                using (var context = new ProjectAdminDAL())
                {
                    if (projectViewModel.ProjectId == 0)
                    {

                        project = new Projects()
                        {
                            ProjectCode = projectViewModel.ProjectCode,
                            ProjectName = projectViewModel.ProjectName,
                            ProjectDescription = projectViewModel.ProjectDescription,
                            CompanyId = projectViewModel.CompanyId,
                            DepartmentId = projectViewModel.DepartmentId,
                            Active = projectViewModel.IsProjectActive,
                            CreatedDate = DateTime.UtcNow,
                        };
                        context.Projects.Add(project);
                        context.SaveChanges();
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        project = db.Projects.Find(projectViewModel.ProjectId);
                            //Single(x => x.ProjectId == projectViewModel.ProjectId);

                        project.ProjectName = projectViewModel.ProjectName;
                        project.ProjectCode = projectViewModel.ProjectCode;
                        project.Active = projectViewModel.IsProjectActive;
                        project.ProjectDescription = projectViewModel.ProjectDescription;
                        project.CompanyId = projectViewModel.CompanyId;
                        project.DepartmentId = projectViewModel.DepartmentId;
                       

                        context.Entry(project).State = EntityState.Modified;
                        context.SaveChanges();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (InvalidCastException ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }

        return RedirectToAction("ProjectDetails", "Project");
    }
```

Entity Model Class

```
public class Projects
{
   
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }

    public string ProjectName { get; set; }

    public string ProjectCode { get; set; }

    public string ProjectDescription { get; set; }

    public bool Active { get; set; }

    public int CompanyId { get; set; }

    public string ProjectManagementId { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }

    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }

    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
           
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class ProjectViewModel
{
    private IList<SelectListItem> m_departmentList;
    private IList<SelectListItem> m_companyList;
    private ProjectAdminDAL db = new ProjectAdminDAL();

    public ProjectViewModel()
    {

        var companies = db.Companies.ToList<Company>();
        Company1 = companies;
        m_companyList = new List<SelectListItem>();

        foreach (var company in companies)
        {
            m_companyList.Add(new SelectListItem()
            {
                Value = company.CompanyId.ToString(),
                Text = company.CompanyName
            });
        }
        var departments = db.Departments.ToList<Department>();
        Departments1 = departments;
        m_departmentList = new List<SelectListItem>();

        foreach(var department in departments)
        {
            m_departmentList.Add(new SelectListItem()
            {
                Value = department.DepartmentId.ToString(),
                Text = department.DepartmentName
            });
        }

       

    }
    [Key]
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Project Name")]
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Project Code")]
    public string ProjectCode { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Description")]
    public string ProjectDescription { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Active")]
    public bool IsProjectActive { get; set; }

    public string ProjectManagementId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Created Timestamp")]
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Department")]
    public int DepartmentId{ get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Department")]
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Company")]
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Company")]
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    
    
    [Display(Name = "Actions")]
    public string Actions { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Company> Company1 { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Department")]
    public IEnumerable<Department> Departments1 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I would try with attach instead... so context.Attach(project).State = EntityState.Modified;  With "entry" you may have to update every field.  (they're all set as "dirty")

Comment: @pcalkins It gives the same error on 'Attach'

Comment: Why do you need to change the State after updating the properties like that?

Comment: @mxmissile how will I tell the context that I am updating the recordS?

Comment: I think it's already attached after using .find()...  you have already done the lookup, so project object is there and attached so just using save changes should update.  (It's not a viewmodel object... it's db entry.)

Comment: Updating your properties should flag it as "Modified" automatically. I'm not sure how EF handles this, but nHibernate uses a dynamic proxy to handle it for you.

Comment: @pcalkins I tried with just context.savechanges() but does not save the entry.

Comment: @pcalkins project is an entity class projectviewmodel class that has the properties hold the data from the view and is attached to the DB.

Comment: @pcalkins I found out the issue. I was calling the entity class department and company virtually which was not allowing to save the changes if you can see at the end of that file.I think we good now. Thank you so much.

Comment: good to hear... added ForeignKey(s) to fix?

Comment: @pcalkins No foreign keys were already there. Removed     public virtual Department Department { get; set; }     public virtual Company Company { get; set; } these 2 from entity model class.